# Print HTML checkbox with complex styles

Tags: html, css

My question is simple. How to get a green checkbox with white check to print (Ctrl + P) as it is.

(This works using Bootstrap 4.0.0. But it is to be used with bootstrap 3.3.7.)

With this HTML and CSS I have managed to get a green check box on the browser. But when i print it, it goes black and white.

```css
.checkbox_class {
     padding-left: 5px;
     margin-top: 0 !important;
     margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
 .checkbox_class label {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     padding-left: 5px;
}
 .checkbox_class label::before {
     content: "";
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 17px;
     height: 17px;
     left: 0;
     margin-left: -20px;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     border-radius: 3px;
     background-color: #fff;
     -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
     transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
 .checkbox_class label::after {
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     margin-left: -20px;
     padding-left: 3px;
     padding-top: 1px;
     font-size: 11px;
     color: #555555;
}
 .checkbox_class input[type="checkbox"] {
     opacity: 0;
}
 .checkbox_class input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
     outline: thin dotted;
     outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
     outline-offset: -2px;
}
 .checkbox_class input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     content: "\f00c";
}
 .checkbox_class input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
     opacity: 0.65;
}
 .checkbox_class input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
     background-color: #eeeeee;
     cursor: not-allowed;
}
 .checkbox_class_success input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
     background-color: #5cb85c;
     border-color: #5cb85c;
}
 .checkbox_class_success input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
     color: #fff;
}
 .checkbox_class{
     padding-left: 21px !important;
     margin-right: 20px !important;
     margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
 .checkbox_class {
     padding-left: 21px !important;
}
 .checkbox_class_success input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
     background-color: #5cb85c;
     border-color: #5cb85c;
}
 .checkbox_class_success input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox_class checkbox_class_success">
       <input id="check_id" value="2" type="checkbox">
       <label for="check_id">Test</label>
    </div>
```

Or is there any other code generating this green check box that can be printed? The checkbox needs to look like this [image]

This is the issue;
[image]

Comment: its already working.. you are generating 2 checkbox in which one is same as you want

Comment: which browser? If the checkbox is printed, it will be black and white in chrome for sure.

Comment: no in firefox and chrome its working fine.. in firefox it is showing 2 checkbox one is behind green

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, too. But this will of course largely depend on whether the user has set their browser to print background colors, or not (the latter is usually the default, to prevent wasting ink/toner by, say, printing a black page background all over the white sheet of paper ...)

Comment: I have added images of the issue. Do you get a colored checkbox instead of the check box that i have rounded in blue pen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem.

**In Safari:**

[image]

When you try to print the page, some options of printing will come up. The circled option, which in english means 'Print background colors', enables you to print the green background of the checkbox (as the preview on the left shows)

**In Chrome:**

[image]

When the printing options pop up, you would have to click on the button 'More settings', when you do so, in the section 'Opzioni', which is translated as 'Options', you have to check the box that says 'Background graphics'. Doing so you will be able to print your background color

Hope this will help

Comment: Great job! The answer is correct here. But when i do that in my project website, it is not working. Let me check what is wrong.

Comment: Which browser are you using @anil_pulikoden ?

Comment: Yes.. in my project i am using bootstrap 3.3.7. It works correctly in 4.0.0 but not in 3.3.7. I have changed it in the question. So the question is rephrased to how achieve the said print functionality using bootstrap 3.3.7.  can u figure it out?